# AJAX Calender User Control Next and Previous button Issue

Tags: ajax, calendarextender

I created Ajax Calender Extender as a user control and using the same in various pages. My problem with the calender user control is, When I click on the Next and Previous buttons in the calender It is not navigating previous month or next month.

AJAX version is : 4.1.40412.2

AJAX Calendar CSS :

.ajax_*calendar
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    background-color: Red;
}
.ajax*_calendar iframe
{
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
}

Here is my user Control is :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCCalender.ascx.cs"
Inherits="test.Web.Pages.UserControls.UCCalender" %>
```

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxControl" %>

```
<div style="position:relative;border:solid 1px red;">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" MaxLength="10" CssClass="txtBox medium" ToolTip="DD/MM/YYYY"
    Style="width: 85px;" Font-Size="11px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/calendar.gif" ID="imgCalender" runat="Server"
    BorderWidth="0" ImageAlign="absmiddle" />
<ajaxControl:CalendarExtender ID="AjaxCalenderCtrl" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupPosition ="TopLeft" 
    TargetControlID="txtDate" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday" PopupButtonID="imgCalender">
</ajaxControl:CalendarExtender>
<ajaxControl:TextBoxWatermarkExtender WatermarkCssClass="watermark" ID="txtWaterMarkDate"
    runat="server" WatermarkText="DD/MM/YYYY" TargetControlID="txtDate">
</ajaxControl:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpvalEndDateEdit" ErrorMessage="!" ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d"
    ControlToValidate="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </div>
```

And I am using the same UserControl in the pages in this way:

```
 <table id="inputDetails" style="padding: 0px; width: 700px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 198px; position: relative" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBeginning" runat="server" Text="Beginning :" Style="margin-left: 10px;"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBeginCalendar" TabIndex="3" runat="server" Style="width: 85px;" Font-Size="11px"></asp:TextBox>


                            <asp:ImageButton ID="BeginCal" runat="server" ImageUrl= "~/Resources/Images/calendar.gif" />
                                  <uc1:UCCalender ID="UCCalStartDate" runat="server" />
                                </td>

                        </table>
```

Please provide the solution for this post.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens when you browse the CalendarExtender in IE8. You need to add the following CSS class to have the problem solved:
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_title
{
 border: none;  /* Fixes the "previous" and "next" buttons in the popup title */ 
}

This is explained here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/22894

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this same issue. It was seemingly being caused because I had applied position:relative to the parent element.

Adding this this CSS fixed the issue for me:

```
.ajax__calendar_prev, .ajax__calendar_next{z-index:1;}
```

Hope that helps!